# What type of form input to be expected from a user that would yield null in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not sure if my question is clear enough, but consider the following function:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;

    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I don't get is "null"; I understand that an empty string "" indicates nothing has been inputted, but what would be the type of input by a user that would imply `null`?

Comment: By type, do you mean `<input TYPE="..">`?

Comment: The code is flawed. `x==null` is true for many more `x` than just `null`.

Comment: Let me guess: you got this crap from w3schools :-)

Comment: This originates from w3schools. Ditch that code. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Comment: oh well..i'm learning from w3schools thats true..not my only source but i thought it's a good site :) thx for cooperation all.

Comment: There should be a `w3fools` tag for SO that you can add to a question if you find out that it has to do with code from their website.

Comment: @Ian perhaps edit in a paragraph, saying "Admittably, I didn't read [w3fools.com]" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value` attribute of an `input` element returns a string, which will contain the text inputted by the user, or otherwise it will be empty (`""`). There is not and should not be a reason to check for `null` in the condition because a string (empty or not) can *never* be equal to `null`.

Comment: Yeah but w3schools says you need it, so you do need it. :)

Comment: @JanDvorak Again? I think this is their first time. Great track record, if you ask me!

Comment: @Ian you can never be sure